# href to wordpress generated li

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm making a wordpress theme but have a small problem

I have a custom page called  catagory. Its a custom page.
I use this code to display a list of all  catagory

```
wp_list_categories('title_li=&orderby=name&show_count=1'); ?>
```

This works all fine. Its generates a list of li objects of all catagorys which are a link to a page with all the post in this catagory.

so the out

```
<ul id="tagsul">
<li class="cat-item cat-item-31"><a href="http://www.hicheck.nl/?cat=31"  
title="Alle berichten opgeslagen onder Art &amp; Design bekijken">Art &amp; Design</a>        
</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-38"><a href="http://www.hicheck.nl/?cat=38" 
title="Alle berichten opgeslagen onder filmpjes bekijken">filmpjes</a> (3)
</li>
</ul>
```

Now my question:
How can I make instead of only the text a link the whole li.. Cuz the li is very large. but only the part where the text displays is clickable at this moment..

Greetings,
Merijn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the anchor inside of the `li` as a block-level element. Add this to your CSS:

```
#tagsul li.cat-item a {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hmm yeah.. So You suggest I make an invisible block which is clickable?

Comment: No, not at all. This CSS amendment simply changes the display type of the existing anchor, allowing it to occupy all of the available width allowed by the `li`. No need for invisible blocks, or anything strange like that.